# Method "Inheriting" other's method parameters

Tags: c#, methods, parameters, parameter-passing

I was wondering if c# offers any way to make the methods "inherit" their parameters and allow to work with them instead of just passing parameters list to the second method again. Here's how it'd possibly work:

```
 void Method1(string p1, int p2, bool p3)
{
    string result = Method2(p1,p2,p3);
}
string Method2():Method1()
{
  if(p3)
    {
      return p1 + p2.ToString();
    }
  else
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

instead of

```
    void Method1(string p1, int p2, bool p3)
{
    string result = Method2(p1,p2,p3);
}
string Method2(string p1, int p2, bool p3)
{
  if(p3)
    {
      return p1 + p2.ToString();
    }
  else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Not sure if it actually makes any sense, but I'm curious if it's possible. If not, do you have any workaround in mind which would let avoid rewriting these parameters to Method2()?

Comment: take a look at this .. is this something you are trying to accomplish if now please try to explain better.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13536993/constructor-parameters-and-inheritance

Comment: Your example doesnt provide a good reason for why this should make sense. There is no apparent reason for Method1 to exist.
Also the answer is no, it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

NO, there is no such construct present and even it would have been there it won't make sense inheriting methods parameter. At the max, in second method you can make them optional parameter saying

```
 void Method1(string p1, int p2, bool p3)
{
    string result = Method2(p1,p2,p3);
}

string Method2(string p1 = null, int p2 = 10, bool p3 = false)
{
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't inherit parameters. Is the issue that you have lots of methods with the same signature all passing around the same set of parameters, and you don't want to have to maintain them all when you make a change?
If you have an "entity" of multiple values that you're passing around then that's when we might normally create a class.

```
public class WhateverTheseParametersAre
{
    public string P1 {get;set;}
    public string P2 {get;set;}
    public bool P3 {get;set;}
}
```

That also eliminates the need for optional/default parameters.

Comment: yeah, i guess wrapping these variables into a class/tuple makes the most sense. Actually i asked the question out of curiocity rather than a real problem. I was trying to achieve something with Reflection and params[] keyword, but it'd probably would be ineffective anyway