# No parameterless constructor defined for an imported object type to be deserialized from JSON

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, javascriptserializer, missingmethodexception

```
Dim result = New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of SearchResult)(Request.Cookies.Get("user").Value)
```

> An exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in System.Web.Extensions.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult'.

I see there have been many questions regarding this issue, but the required object types were self-defined class, so the solution would be to create a new and parameterless constructor for that class.

In my case, I am trying to use `SearchResult` from namespace `System.DirectoryServices` as the object type to be deserialized from JSON String. How can I solve it?

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13536993/constructor-parameters-and-inheritance

Comment: @BrianRogers but my issue is not 'Method not found'...

Answer (score 0):

You can't deserialise a [`SearchResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.searchresult?view=netframework-4.8) object because it has no public constructor.

In theory you could write a [`JavaScriptConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) and [use reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/708952/397817) to instantiate an instance of the target class in the convertor's `Deserialize()` method but that would be hackery of the first order.

Either serialize and deserialize a custom class of your own making, or rethink what you're doing.